# Why an image of clouds made of dots as an ad?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, advertising

I was reading a question on Stack Overflow, and noticed that in the right side there was an empty ad, which consisted only of clouds over a blue sky:

[image: Sky ad]

It seemed curious to me that there were no info in the ad: no logo, no text, just a sky full of clouds. So I checked the source of the component, and noticed that it was not an image, but a group of DIVs, and the clouds where drawed using dots and CSS styles.

[image: HTML inspector]

Just by mere curiosity, why is this ad empty, and instead of an image, it is an elaborated composite made of divs and text?

Comment: I prefer blue skies over ads so much!

Comment: Stack Overflow runs on the cloud.

Comment: @guillermogutierrez What I find confusing is that this campaign is geotargeted to Canada-- but according to your profile you're in El Salvador. That said: thanks for the heads up! :-)

Comment: Oh, there will be no clouds anymore :( I liked them, they were very creative. I thought it was something like [this](http://responsiveicons.co.uk/). You're welcome @stevvve :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While I like @Mitchell Carroll's answer, that is incorrect. The clouds are due to an ad tag being implemented improperly.

The error is fixed, so you will no longer see any [happy clouds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raXanYjTF18).

Comment: Oww. No philanthropists on SO, eh?

Comment: @Jongware Not just yet. I truly believe that one day, someone or a group of someones will do what Mitchell Caroll suggested happened here.

Comment: Just FYI - I'm seeing this again today, perhaps the philanthropists have bought some ads now :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Hahaha grrrreat. This is fixed now, and it shouldn't come up for another 29 days or so, at least. :-)

Comment: @stevvve FWIW, I've been seeing them on and off throughout the month still, including today :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe I've notified the relevant people, but they're moving at turtle-with-no-legs speed. Methinks you have another ~six days of clouds. :-)

Comment: @stevvve haha - I should probably keep quiet, clouds are a nice distraction from adverts :)

Comment: "The error is fixed"? [Is Stack Overflow advocating nice weather?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349673/4532996)

Comment: @cat This error was reporting more than two years ago-- this issue is specific to an individual campaign, so it's very easy for this to happen on more than one occasion.

Comment: I'm seeing clouds again.  Should I do anything?

Comment: @zero298 Info about where you're located and any info about where on the site you saw it, ie: tags on the question you were viewing when you saw it.

Comment: @stevvve I'm in the US and I'm seeing it on the homepage with no tags searched.

Comment: @zero298 grrrrrrrrrrrreaaaaaaaaaaaaaat. okay, we'll get back on it. new month, new clouds, apparently.

Comment: @stevvve I'm only getting it while logged in to FireFox it seems.  If you'd like more explicit information on location or potential network conditions, I'd be willing to discuss it in a private channel.

Comment: It's back it seems https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334795/what-is-this-ad-actually-for

Answer (score 13):

It's likely the result of someone who is very well versed in HTML and CSS, and also believes that SO deserves to run without ads.  Instead of just straight donating to SO, they bought up an ad in order to contribute to SO's development and upkeep, while also preventing an amount of real (possibly invasive and annoying) ads from showing up on people's screens.