# Is Stack Overflow advocating nice weather?

Tags: bug, advertising, sidebar

I just saw the following ad in the sidebar:

[image: clouds]

What exactly is this an ad for?

Is it just me, or is there some information missing here?

When I inspect the frame, all I see is code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">cloud();</script>
<div class="dvbs_cloud" style="font-size:300px; width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 34px; left: 28px;">.</div>
```

Comment: Did you click on it?

Comment: @Bugs I tried. Nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: They are in the Cloud?

Comment: This is on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @stevvve Yes. I even reloaded the page a few times and got the ad again.

Comment: Grrrrrrrrreat. I'm probably breaking things in relation to this question. I'll take a look. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296330/are-community-open-source-ads-showing-up-anywhere/296348

Comment: Important question, @TotZam: where are you located?

Comment: @stevvve New York

Comment: @TotZam Generally this is displayed when an advertiser's ad is shown outside of a prescribed geography. Any chance you're using a VPN? Cuz I'm in New York and can't seem to repro this one. Any additional info: tag(s) or question(s) where you can see it, frequency, is very helpful.

Comment: @stevvve I'm looking at the main [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). I'm not using VPN. I don't have any tags or filters selected. When I keep reloading my page, I see this ad on every 2nd to 5th reload, obviously not exact since of the randomness.

Comment: @TotZam That narrows it down to one of two: Microsoft or IBM, as they are running large volumes of run-of-site inventory. Being that the IBM campaign is pretty new, I'm gonna assume you're not seeing those and that they're the culprit.

Comment: @stevvve I just reloaded the page around 10 times. I saw 3 Microsoft ads and no IBM ads, so that sounds like that might be the problem.

Comment: @TotZam The fun part is: it's geotargeted to the United States, and you're *in* the United States. So you shouldn't be seeing clouds. I'll reach out to the client.

Comment: It currently is quite cloudy outside by me, so at least this is an accurate weather report :)

Comment: @stevvve I'm also getting the clouds (I'm out in Chicago). Posting in case that helps (but I suspect at this point, the problem's been identified).

Comment: I started reading this question, but then I got distracted by an inexplicable craving for popcorn.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Now I can't stop seeing popcorn!

Comment: This has occurred before: [Why an image of clouds made of dots as an ad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292332/why-an-image-of-clouds-made-of-dots-as-an-ad)

Comment: So basically, if a company puts a meaningless pretty picture up, people are way more likely to click on it than an actual ad ... Why didn't anyone think of this before?

Comment: Cumulus propaganda...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**You betcha!**

This is part of a larger initiative the Ad Sales and Operations team here at Stack Overflow is taking on to promote a love of clouds and blue skies. We've noticed that recently many Stack Overflow users are moving away from enjoying things like blue skies and and fluffy clouds, and we think that's sad. So we'll be rolling out way more ads with that beautiful view in the coming weeks, months, years, and decades, because we believe that blue skies and clouds are just *the best*.

.../jokes

What's *actually* going on here is that some campaigns by advertisers use DoubleVerify to monitor delivery of their ads. DoubleVerify wrappers accomplish a handful of things, but one of the principal goals is to ensure that ads are only served in their prescribed geographies. We're operating under the assumption that there is something amiss with the geo-blocking set up by DoubleVerify, and reached out to inform them. In the meantime, enjoy the clouds!

As always, any relevant updates will appear below. Also as always: thank you for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: I've heard myths of the sky and clouds. It talks of a land called "outside" where only the most brave/foolish developers should tread... Staying safe in the basement, with a fast connection, takeaway pizza and caffeine drip is rumoured to be the safest and most normal. :-)

Comment: Can you add some grass too? I remember once seeing grass somewhere.

Comment: @TotZam  Grass? What is that??

Comment: I've accepted this answer since the first part must be correct. The rest of this answer seems unrelated.

Comment: I'm already seeing the [increase](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EDd5a.png) you are referring to. (Seems to be just a taller ad.)

Comment: @stevvve I just tested again and while I am still seeing a bunch of clouds, I did get one [IBM ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFzBh.png). I also got one [bad gateway error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uACEf.png).

Comment: Wait, The first part of your answer was actual a joke? I think it actual would be good for us programmers to get of the computer for a bit and enjoy some fresh air. That's what I thought you all were promoting.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this functionality:)  It's working fine here ATM, (UK), and would appreciate it if you could continue to publish it until, say, the end of October.

Comment: apparently, you can only see this if you have windows.

Comment: You know what's outside? *Outsiders*. You know, the people the Elders have specifically forbidden us from interacting with. If you're seeing clouds, *you are in danger*. Return to a safe zone immediately.

Comment: What will happen to us all when [the machine stops](http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/prajlich/forster.html)?

Comment: I really wish that first bit were true. ):

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Wait what? You actually need "Windows" for something? Maybe I should have saved the install disk for my Windows XP computer from ~15 years ago... ;)

Comment: @stevvve - You might be interested in this question: [Speeding up Stack Overflow page loads?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350437/608639)

Comment: @stevvve The skies of Stack Overflow seemed to have turned cloudy once again. Should I make new meta posts whenever I notice these clouds appearing frequently to report it?

Comment: This has regressed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334795/what-is-this-ad-actually-for , CC: @JonClements