# Speeding up Stack Overflow page loads due to doubleverify.com requests?

Tags: support, advertising

I've noticed Stack Overflow pages have slowed down considerably. Stack Overflow pages are unresponsive for the first 1/2 second to 1 second after following a link for a question.

I think the slow down is due to `doubleverify.com`. The browser's status bar shows the page is waiting on the domain, and the Firefox developer console shows some non-trivial delays. Its not uncommon to see 16 or 20 fetches to `doubleverify.com`, with some taking 250 ms to 400 ms (many take less time).

[image]

Other suspects include `serving-sys.com`, but the status bar does not point the finger at them. The status bar definitely fingers `doubleverify.com`.

I run fully patched Firefox with one plug-in, so I don't believe its due to issues on my side. The plug-in is [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) from the EFF.

Is there anything we can do to speed things up on our side? Are there any opt-outs available to us?

If I install an ad blocker and stop `doubleverify.com` traffic, will it harm the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: I tried filtering the network requests from SO by `doubleverify` + `serving-sys` and I don't see any request for those domains. The site load very fast here, so maybe I missed anything?

Comment: DoubleVerify is [used to monitor ad delivery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349675/3614835).

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey. I guess my next question is, can we safely block them? I don't want to cut into Stack Exchange revenue, but... If I am give a choice between a stalled web page versus an ad, then the ad looses every time. I'd be happy to revisit if DoubleVerify can improve their operations.

Comment: @Jeffrey - I installed [AdBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) and added a custom rule that blocked `doubleverify.com`. The AdBlock rule for them is [`||doubleverify.com^`](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5275). The pages are loading as expected. Maybe someone from Stack Exchange can reach out to them and alert them of a possible issue.

Answer (score 30):

`doubleverify.com` isn't something we use ourselves, though there might be something external adding it. It's not showing up on my side, for example. Such a drastic decrease in performance will surely be noticed if it happened to a lot of people, as well.

From higher to lower probability:

- The ads you see might include it. Is this something which happens on every page load however? Or only sometimes?
- Your browser/computer might be infected in some way, and the doubleverify.com is injected, alongside other ads possibly. Does doubleverify.com appear on other websites? Do you see ads that seem out of place / bad quality? We try to have good ads, not intrusive etc.
- Your ISP might be injecting ads with their own tracking. Does doubleverify.com appear on other websites?

Comment: The ISP shouldn't be able to MITM since it's an HTTPS connection. Unless they've installed a root cert, which would really fall under the "infected" category.

Comment: Thanks Horia. I went to a different machine with a different OS. The machine was fully patched with a fully patched Firefox; but it lacked HTTPS Everywhere. Stack Overflow pages were making requests to `doubleverify.com`.

Comment: Thanks again Horia. Would my region factor into things? I'm in Northeast US; IP address in the 71.244.247.x block.

Comment: From http://www.doubleverify.com/ : "DV ensures you only pay for ads that are viewable." It's view tracking for ads.

Comment: I saw 'doubleverify.com' flash past while an SO page was loaded.  The question [Is Stack Overflow advocating nice weather](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349673/is-stack-overflow-advocating-nice-weather) indicates that some advertisers use the services of doubleverify.com to ensure that ads are being delivered appropriately.  The two connections cost about 170 ms each on my work network — I didn't see them on my home machine, but I do have AdBlocker installed there and not on my work machine.  Dunno if that's any help beyond confirming that sometimes SO pages reference that site.